# how to install jautodoc in eclipse mars version

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi i am trying to install jautodoc in my mars version but i got following error please help me

HTTP Server 'Service Unavailable': http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/update/content.xml
HttpComponents connection error response code 503.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In your eclipse you can get it from help -->Eclipse MarketPlace --> search for jAutodoc this is one way.. If it is not supporting in your eclipse
```

2nd way is copy from your old eclipse pluggins
go to your eclipse pluggins location ........

C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins and copy the net.sf.jautodoc.velocity_1.12   jar
net.sf.jautodoc_1.12.jar (if u have in your previous eclipse)

Comment: where am finding these jars

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable**

> The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle
>   the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the
>   server

Please check attached screen shot SourceForge is under maintenance mode

[image]

Comment: k thanQ very much Subodh Joshi